# concatenate mysql select query with php variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to concatenate a MySQL `SELECT` query with PHP variable but got an error.
My PHP statement which gives an error is:

```
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,username,add FROM users WHERE username =".$user."AND password=".$add);
```

and error as:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: info in C:\wamp\www\pollBook\poll\login.php on line 18
Call Stack
```

I don't understand where I missed the code.
When I write query without `WHERE` clause it works fine.

Comment: No your error is about a missing variable $info on line 18, not your query. Also DON'T use mysql_* AND DO escape your query, you don't even have quotes around the input.

Comment: It seems this error is not related with this line.

Comment: `mysql_query` is a deprecated function. You should look at MySQLi or PDO_MySQL. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: When you say error, its only a notice. I don't think it can stop the query from executing.

Comment: @jtheman my sql query statement which i paste above is on line no.18. Actually i am new with all this stuff and i don't understand your statement"quotes around the input" will u be please tell me what input exactly?

Comment: @GBRocks Actually i wants to display output of this query in json query works f9 when not concatenate with variables. and now i m tierd of it

Comment: See the error refers to an undefined variable called `$info` in login.php on line 18. There is no variable like that on the line you posted. Are u sure you are looking at login.php on line 18?

Comment: You will be even more tired when someone easily hacks your database! Look into the answers about PDO below.

Comment: @jtheman yup i m looking for login.php and ok i going to look answers abot PDO..thanx

Comment: @jtheman it's juz a simple webpage form which accepts username and it's address. Database contains only simple strings of it and php accepts and display them..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The reason why your code isn't working**

You are attempting to use a variable, `$info`, that has not been defined. When you attempt to use an undefined variable, you're effectively concatenating nothing into a string, however because PHP is loosely typed, it declares the variable the second you reference it. That is why you're seeing a `notice` and not a `fatal error`. You should go through your code, and ensure that `$info` gets a value assigned to it, and that it is not overwritten at some point by another function. However, more importantly, read below.

---

**Stop what you are doing**

---

This is vulnerable to a type of attack called an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I'm not going to tell you how to concatenate SQL strings. It's terrible practice.

You should **NOT** be using mysql functions in PHP. They are deprecated. Instead use the PHP PDO Object, with prepared statements. Here's a rather good [tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

**Example**

---

After you've read [this tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), you'll be able to make a PDO Object, so I'll leave that bit for you.

The next stage is to add your query, using the `prepare` method:

```
$PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE `id` = :id");
// Loads up the SQL statement. Notice the :id bit.
$actualID = "this is an ID";
$PDO->bindParam(':id', $actualID);
// Bind the value to the parameter in the SQL String.
$PDO->execute();
// This will run the SQL Query for you.
```

Comment: Can't agree more. However this is not at all an answer to the question.

Comment: Why give OP an answer that encourages bad practise. OP ultimately wants to query the DB. May as well get them to do it the right way.

Comment: Well the problem that the OP posted is apparently not connected with the query line. I agree you could strongly encourage him to change his code but this is still not the answer to his question. So add this as a comment.

Comment: I think I'll just amend my answer to answer OP's question, then have this as a side note. Makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing space before "AND " and you should use single quotes as suggested in other answers.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,username,add FROM users WHERE *username =".$user."AND* password=".$add);
```

Updated:

```
echo $sql = "SELECT user_id,username,add FROM users WHERE username ='".$user."' AND password='".$add."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: check the updated answer.. I just echoed the sql part.. see what you get on the screen (if needed add die after echo)

Answer (score 0):

although there is no $info variable used in the query but you need to correct the query:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,username,add FROM users WHERE username ='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $add . "'");
```

Comment: Actually we have no idea how the contents of `$user` and `$add` look like! This is not either an answer for the OP's question!

Comment: It's actually not a bad answer despite the poor php/mysql practise. OP basically didn't surround the `$user` and `$add` variables with quotes so they were't being passed as a string in the query resulting in the error.

Comment: @harryg Well it is a bad answer if you are looking to solve the error: `Undefined variable: info`

Comment: @jtheman: the basic has to be correct first. I know that the solution is found in my advice but the syntax has to be corrected and I only did that, I even mentioned that in my explanation.

Comment: @jtheman: I dont want an upvote for this, its just the syntax was not right and thats the basic, it should be advised. I am sorry if that shouldn’t have been done..

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Still you don't know if the syntax was wrong. He could easily had defined the variables before `$user = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'"; ` so the answer is not useful. Also if you really want to help do not encourage using deprecated mysql_* functions at all.

Answer (score 0):

First from the error its looks like one of your variables is not defined. .. check it. Second surround your parameters with ' for safer syntax.

Comment: You can't tell from the code posted IF the OP has escaped his query or not, whatever you might think.

Answer (score -2):

This is because the variables you are using might not have defined above

So first initialize your variables or if its coming from somewhere else(POST or GET) then check with **isset** method

So complete code would be

```
$user = 123; // or $user = isset($user)?$user:123;
$add = 123456; // or $add = isset($add)?$add:123456;
```

And then run your query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,username,add FROM users WHERE username =".$user."AND password=".$add);
```

Comment: The error is `Undefined variable: info` and has nothing to do with that line.