# mysql update query with php variable and dots around it

Tags: php, mysql, variables, evaluate

So, I'm learning PHP and I have a question about the part underlined in my screenshot:

http://s18.postimg.org/8el9lkpuh/image.png

I read these related questions and they were generally helpful (and I realize there are security concerns not handled here) but didn't help my understand my specific question:

[concatenate mysql select query with php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293199/concatenate-mysql-select-query-with-php-variable)

[MySQL query with PHP variables Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252522/mysql-query-with-php-variables-issues)

My question is, why do we need these dots around the variable? Are these concatenation dots? I don't think we are concatenating anything, we're just evaluating a variable, no? And why does it need quotation marks around it? Why can't it simply be "UPDATE table WHERE name=$name" and let $name evaluate to whatever it is..? 
In fact, when I try to do that it just doesn't evaluate, but why? 
A few lines below, `echo "<p>Name: $row[1]</p>";`, $row for example evaluates just fine...

EDIT:

`$q='UPDATE towels SET name="$name" WHERE id=1';`
output: $name
my variable is inside doublequotes, so it should get evaluated, but doesn't?

`$q='UPDATE towels SET name="$name" WHERE id=1';`
output: $name
variable inside doublequotes, should get evaluated, but doesn't?

`$q='UPDATE towels SET name="'.$name.'" WHERE id=1';`
output: CORRECT!
variable inside singlequotes, shouldn't get evaluated, but does?

`$q="UPDATE towels SET name='$name' WHERE id=1";`
output: CORRECT!
variable  inside singlequotes, shouldn't get evaluated, but does?

So clearly I'm missing something because it all seems opposite than it should be to me.

Comment: You are concatenating with `.` and you can do `"UPDATE table WHERE name='$name'" `

Comment: Why do we need to concatenate? -- also, when I do what you wrote, the output is always simply $name (and not "John" or whatever the name should be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` is indeed a concatenation operator.

When the statement you underlined is processed, the bits in between `''` are processed **literally**, and those outside the `''` are evaluated.

Because you want `$name` to be converted to it's value (rather than just having the text `$name` within your SQL), you must put it outside the `''`, and the `.` just tells the compiler to package the whole statement into one long concatenated string.

Take a look at this ... http://phphowto.blogspot.co.uk/2006/12/concatenate-strings.html ... for more information about concatenation.

`echo` allows for a different way of using variable values (they are evaluated within the `echo` argument ... see here for details ... http://php.net/Echo

---

In answer to your comment, you need to imagine that statement as three distinct blocks `UPDATE Towels SET Name="` is the first part of the string, `$name` is the second part, and `" WHERE Id=1` is the third part.

They all come together to say `UPDATE Towels SET Name="John" WHERE Id=1`.

You need the `""` around the `John` value because that is the format expect in the SQL statement - and since you want those `""` taken literally, they belong inside the `''`.

It's confusing to start with, but you will get the hang of it!

Comment: Thank you for the detail -- understood. But in my case, my $name variable is inside single quotes, and it's still evaluating! That's what's confusing me! I'll edit my post to explain my question better...

Comment: so you are saying this is the best way to write it? `$q="UPDATE towels SET name='".$name."' WHERE id=1";` because this is not what i had initially.. initially I had `$q="UPDATE towels SET name="'.$name.'" WHERE id=1";` and it stilled worked, i.e. the single quotes were inside the doublequotes, which should mean no evaluation, but it took place..?

Comment: You can use `"` and `'` interchangeably in php ... you can put `'` inside `""` and it will be interpreted literally, and vice versa. I'm not surprised you are finding it confusing, because it is ... only experience will diminish your confusion!

Comment: and what about standard escaping of the doublequotes, it actually works for me, but is it bad practice in PHP/SQL? `$q="UPDATE towels SET name=\"$name\" WHERE id=1";`

Comment: Yes, you could escape them if you wanted ... it's not bad practice, but using `'` inside `""` makes for more readable code (as long as your SQL Engine is expecting `'` as the text delimiter - if not then you would use the opposite scheme ... `"` inside `' '`.

Comment: I would probably recommend you spend 30 minutes creating a load of different strings with `"` and `'` in, and see if you get the results you expect ...concatenate some of those bad boys together too :0)

Comment: understood, OK, I think I've wrapped my head around it. a bit. thank you for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82944/discussion-between-user3399551-and-3-14159265358979323846264).

Comment: this works in my case
"UPDATE products SET `image` = '$image' WHERE id = $product_id"